# Is it possible to use too many functions in Python?

Tags: python

This kind of a broad question.

As I find myself having to write longer and longer scripts, I find that my instinct is to break everything up into bite-sized functions; however, this ultimately results in functions calling functions calling functions calling functions.... and I'm wondering if I'm completely thinking about this the wrong way.

Here's what an abridged script might look like. Sorry it's kind of contrived.

```
def simple_task_1():
    return

def simple_task_2():
    return

def simple_task_3():
    return

def simple_task_4():
    return

def complex_task_1():
    simple_task_2()
    simple_task_3()
    simple_task_4()
    return

def startup():
    simple_task_1()
    complex_task_1()
    simple_task_4()

def finish():
    # other function calls
    return

def main():
    startup()
    finish()
```

So, is this the correct way to be using functions? Is there an objective point where you can say you've made too many function calls inside each other? Should I even be making functions for tasks that only end up being done once?

Comment: Ultimately you will want to group, or encapsulate, groups of related functions into classes. The class would also contain any shared state between the functions (now called methods).

Comment: @Keith -- I agree with your statement, however, to clarify, I think that it's important to mention that classes without state to share are pointless.  Perhaps a module with functions is better in this case.  In other words, if every one of your class's methods is able to be decorated with `@staticmethod`, then you probably don't actually want a class.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Python has a "recursion" limit.  If you hit that, then you're probably using too many functions, otherwise it's probably not a big deal -- Usually you can only hit the recursion limit if you're calling a function recursively (and then *usually* because you did something wrong and didn't break when you should have).

The point of functions is to make your life easier.  If you find that you have too many functions and you're not actually making your life easier, then it's probably a problem.  For example:

```
def add(x,y):
    return x+y
```

Is a pretty pointless function and it's probably best avoided, however, if you want `sinc`:

```
def sinc(x):
    return math.sin(x)/x
```

That might actually be useful since the new function name is more descriptive than the code which is executed within.  Also, later if you find that you need to remove the singularity at x=0, you can add that into `sinc` easily.

Ultimately, readability is what counts.  If using a function makes your code easier to read, then it's probably worthwhile (even if you'll only call it from one place and could inline it easily).  There are some grey areas if you're really concerned about performance (functions do take a little longer to execute than inline code), but you shouldn't use that as an excuse to inline something that is hard to read unless you can reliably demonstrate that it is a performance bottleneck.

Comment: Thank you! I loved all the answers, but yours especially cleared it up for me.

Comment: Note that the max stack depth is shocklingly tiny, limiting how recursive functions can be used.

Answer (score 2):

The main point of functions is to allow code reuse and cleaner code. If it's something really simple that you're only doing once then the function is probably unnecessary.

Having said that, there's nothing explicitly wrong with splitting your code out into looks of functions. If it makes your life easier or your code more readable then go ahead and use them.

Answer (score 2):

Breaking big things into smaller things, be it modules, classes, functions etc., is exactly the way to handle complexity in software. Divide and conquer.

Answer (score 1):

Looks fine, at least in the abstract.

The exact decomposition of the program into functions depends on what the functions do, but if the final result is composed of functions each of which does one task which is fully described by the name of the function, then you're on the right track.

If you find yourself with a very large number of functions that have logical groupings you might consider dividing them into modules.  If you have a lot of functions that use the same data, you might consider creating a class to hold the data and corresponding functions.

Answer (score 1):

You are making a tradeoff. Usually, modularizing your code as you have is a good thing. Most people don't do it enough. It increases code reusability and (usually) readability. But it is possible to take it too far: if you find yourself getting confused by which functions are calling which, and readability starts going down, you might want to reconsider your design.

Another thing to be aware of is that calling a function takes a good amount of overhead, which can be significant. Every time you call a function, an activation record must be created and placed on the [call stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack). For functions that are ridiculously simple, this overhead is not worth it. For example, if you were implementing a sorting function that needed the average of 2 numbers (maybe to choose the pivot of quicksort?), you would be much better off just writing `(a+b)/2` rather than defining a function

```
def avg(a, b):
    return (a+b)/2
```

You've asked a very good question that is definitely something you should be constantly thinking about, but it's obviously quite difficult to give a concrete answer. As you write more and more code, you'll get a better feel for it.

Comment: True, not sure why I did that... fixed.